# Are Apple's iOS frameworks dynamically or statically linked?

Tags: ios

When building iOS apps, frameworks or libraries of my own must be linked statically.
I'm wondering if the executable I built also packed the binaries of Apple's frameworks (like CoreFoundation.framework), or are they loaded dynamically when running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's dynamically linked, cos when you add Frameworks, they aren't packed in the app bundle.